# AngularFire2 5.0 How to read nested data

Tags: angularfire2

I have a firebase database like this one.  I am using angularfire2 5.0 to query the database.

```
groups{
     -L01ocnd1jxL8wOkLqRK{
         groupCode: "2eotrg"
         groupDescription: "Test"
         groupName: "Test"
         members{
          YuKVbvuGTNgw6OmVr4N89XZG88H3{
            mail: "victor@gmail.com"
            name: "Victor"
            subscription{
                -L01ocnkVVLXPNqCyfLi{   
                    rolegroup: 3    
                    state: true;
                }
            }
          }
        }
        rules{
         firsRule: 0
         secondRule: 0
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to render the rules and the members of this group but i can not do it.

I read the group as a list

```
this.items = this.afDB.list('/groups/'+groupKey).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

And in my view i am trying to list the members and rules, but i can not do it.

```
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
                {{item | json}}
        </ion-item>
```

Your help please explain me how to do it.

In previous release fo angularfirebase i use something like this.

```
    <ion-list inset>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
            <div *ngFor="let member of item.mebers">
                {{member | json}}
            </div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution.

The snapshotChanges return an array of SnapshotAction.

```
interface SnapshotAction {
     type: string;
     payload: DatabaseSnapshot;
     key: string;
     prevKey: string | undefined;
}
```

The solution is to read the SnapshotAction.payload that return a standar DabaseSnapshot, and then use the function that firebase provide for this interfaces. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

Here is the code...

```
this.groupRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    console.log(snap.key);

    if(snap.key == 'groupCode'){
      var datasnapshot = snap.payload;
      datasnapshot.val();
      console.log(datasnapshot.val());

    }
    if(snap.key == 'members'){
      var datasnapshot = snap.payload;
      console.log("Snapchot"+JSON.stringify(datasnapshot));
      datasnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(key);
        console.log(childData.mail);
        console.log(childData.subscription);

        var subscriptionsnap = childSnapshot.child("subscription"); 
        console.log(subscriptionsnap);
        subscriptionsnap.forEach(function(subsc){
          console.log(subsc.key);
          var subsdata = subsc.val();
          console.log(subsdata.rolegroup);
        });

    });

    }        

  }
  );

});
```